# create new module for quill ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-quill

everyone, I create this component but I just want to add (**hr**) tag to my text editor (quill react) but I've no idea how to do it with registration and its dependency any help? (USING FUNCTION COMPONENT)

---

and here is class component example . but I want function component:

https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#default-toolbar-elements

```js
import ReactQuill, { Quill } from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
```

and there is my component:

```
Editor.modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ font: [] }],
    [{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike',], // toggled button
    [
      { list: 'ordered' },
      { list: 'bullet' },
      { align: [] },
      { direction: 'rtl' },
    ],
    [{ script: 'sub' }, { script: 'super' }, 'formula'], // superscript/subscript
    ['link', 'image', 'video'],
    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
    ['clean'], // remove formatting button
  ],
  clipboard: {
    // toggle to add extra line breaks when pasting HTML:
    matchVisual: false,
  },
};

export default function Editor() {
  const [ content, setContent] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (html) => {
    setContent(content: html );
   
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.ArticlesQuill}>
      <ReactQuill
        theme='snow'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={content}
        modules={Editor.modules}
        bounds={'.app'}
        placeholder='type something here...'
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you